# how to obtain registration ids when sending push notifications in curl php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, curl

So basically... here are working two files, one is a curlphp script and the other an angular1 js file.

in the js file, When an admin user clicks on 'send notification' an event is triggered in order to send a message by invoking curl through a function.

That function looks like this

```
    $scope.notify = function(title, content, ¿¿ userId ??){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'app/backend/src/curl-service.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            userId: 'the problem is here', 
            title: title, 
            message: content
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('time to use curl service');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Error! you can't use curl service');
        }
    });

    };
```

as you can see, I pass some data with ajax to fill the notification's content that will be pushed by this curl-service.php file

```
<?php
// Incluimos el api asignada al app
define('API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyAJvT_Tx7vwZzViWkwUcQHdhx2osTiSXHA');

$registrationIds = array($_POST['userId']);
$title = array($_POST['title']);
$message = array($_POST['message']);

// preparamos los array
$msg = array
(
    'title'     => $title,
    'message'   => $message,
    'sound'     => default,
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY
);

//iniciamos el servicio conectando con la url
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

//ejecutamos el servicio
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

//verificamos posibles errores y se genera la respuesta 
if ($err) {
    echo "Se ha producido el siguiente error:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
?>
```

What I actually need to know, is how can I obtain the registration ids so then I can use it in my php file too

Comment: You are specifically using AJAX to POST to your PHP script, yet you use the $_GET Array in PHP

Comment: ups, that's literally on me, thanks for that, so... any idea how do I obtain these registrations id? I mean do I get them from a database? from a device? that's what I don't have very clear

Comment: So, your problem is, that you don't get the userIds from the client to the server?

Comment: yep, actually don't know how to do get it, so then I can do whatever I need with it

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is right here in this bit of code:

```
$registrationIds = array($_POST['userId']);
$title = array($_POST['title']);
$message = array($_POST['message']);

// preparamos los array
$msg = array
(
    'title'     => $title,
    'message'   => $message,
    'sound'     => default,
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
)
```

You are creating Arrays from your POST data and then using then as Strings afterwards, if you change the first bit to:

```
$registrationIds = $_POST['userId'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

or even better with security in mind:

```
$registrationIds = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userId', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

You should be good to go

Comment: consider that I'm not even using the script yet, the real problem is I don't know how to get registrations ids before anything, it is required by fcm to work properly

Comment: I said it in the title, maybe I din't explain very clear in the content